# Table data css for dropdown & adress input

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors, css-tables

[image]

I'm using this CSS in a table.
1)Background color vanishes in address & dropdown.
What's the solution.
2)I also want address and dropdown to fill the full table width.
I'm not getting which tag I should use.

Can anyone help? I'm learning it.

```
table,th,td{
border-spacing:2px;
font-size:15px;
font-family:"Georgia";
border-radius:6px;
padding:3px;
border: 1px solid white; }
td{
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#548EA3;
border-spacing:5px; }
td input {/*sof*/
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: can you provide your HTML code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
td textarea, td select {
    width: 98%;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because they are in textarea & select. You have set style only for `td input` set style for textarea and select box

```css
td textarea, td select {
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see your css for select.

```
td select {  
    background-color:#548EA3;
    width: 100%;
}
```